# How can we disable ODBC credentials popup in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, passwords, microsoft-excel-2016, authentication, odbc

Can we disable the ODBC credential popup on refresh of external data
in Excel 2016:
[image: ODBC credential popup]
and, if so, how?

Answer (score -2):

After a quick search i found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/277600/the-password-you-use-to-connect-to-the-server-is-not-saved-when-you-im) on Microsoft Support. That happens because:

> The Allow saving password check box was not selected on the Connection tab of the Data Link Properties dialog box, when the connection to the data source was made.

Comment: I’m not sure what you quote from the link is relevant to OP’s question. -1